# Compile an Android library that contains a third-party .aar dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependency-management, jitpack

I am creating my first, privately hosted Android library on jitpack.

**Issue**: My hosted library contains a third-party `.aar` dependency (Spotify player SDK). The third-party has not yet hosted their library, so I'm stuck with referencing that third-party dependency from my library project via the following:

`repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}`

...

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b@aar'
}`

Of course when I try to host my library on jitpack and compile my library dependency in a sample project, I receive the following error: `Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.`

> Could not resolve com.github.example:my-private-library:0.9.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.github.vertigomedia:my-private-library:0.9.0.
>   Could not parse POM https://jitpack.io/com/github/example/my-private-library/0.9.0/my-private-library-0.9.0.pom
>   Unable to resolve version for dependency 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b:aar'

The `'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b:aar'` library cannot be resolved because it's not remotely hosted anywhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Do I need to privately host the Spotify player library `.aar` myself? I'd prefer not to have to do that for licensing reasons. Can I somehow exclude the `.aar` from my `.pom` file and have the client sample app manually include the Spotify player `.aar` dependency in its `build.gradle` file? Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Do I need to privately host the Spotify player library .aar myself?" -- I would be rather surprised if you are allowed to do that from a licensing standpoint. "Can I somehow exclude the .aar from my .pom file and have the client sample app manually include the Spotify player .aar dependency in its build.gradle file?" -- you could try using `provided` rather than `compile` in your library, and then require apps using your library to `compile` in Spotify's SDK.

Comment: Agreed on the licensing bit. I'd rather not mess with that. Using `provided` did the trick for me. This places a little more work than I'd like for the client app, but I think it's my only option. Thank you for your suggestion! I was not familiar with `provided` until now.